# How to parse or control the control-flow of json stream in golang?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

**Background**

I have big(2Gib<myfile<10GiB) `json` files that I need to parse. Due to the size of the file, I cannot keep it as a variable and unmarshal it as I need.

This is why I am trying to use `json.NewDecoder` as shown in the example [here](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.18#Decoder.Token).

**A bit about data**

The data I have is kinda like the followng,

```
{
   "key1" : [ "hundreads_of_nested_objects" ],
   "key2" : [ "hundreads_of_nested_objects" ],
   "unknown_unexpected_key" : [ "many_nested_objects" ],
   ........
   "keyN" : [ n_objects ]
}
```

**The Code I am trying to use**

```golang
    file, err := os.Open("myfile.json")
    dec := json.NewDecoder(file)
    for {
        t, err := dec.Token()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%T: %v", t, t)
        }
```

**Problem Statement**

1. How should I approach this kind of data structure with the `json.NewDecoder`?
2. What are the best practices to deal with this kind of problem?
3. Pointing out any existing similar code would be helpful.

To clarify, a few use cases could be the followings,

- Parse only `key1` or `keyN` instead of the whole file.
- Grab only a specific key and find some nested object of that key.
- Dump the contents of keys or some objects inside them to another file.

[N.B] I am new to development, my question might be too broad. Any guidance to improve it would be helpful too.

Comment: "Due to the size of the file, I cannot keep it as a variable and unmarshal it as I need"  does that also imply that you can't store all the unmarshaled data the same time also?

Comment: Usually a JSON stream consists of discreet JSON objects or base types, listed one after another in the stream. In your example it appears this is a single JSON object with a large number of fields? If that is the case, you'd need a very custom decoder.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've already written? I mean if all you want to do is to print the type and value of the json's tokens then you are already doing it. If that's not what you want to do then please update your question by explicitly stating your intended purpose for the code.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Yes, I might be doing something wrong because as soon as I performed unmarshal  4Gig of memory has been filled within a few seconds. So I wasn't even trying to print.

Comment: @colm.anseo that's sad. I can't even approach this problem, I am not sure how I would write a custom decoder. What if I ignore the top-level object and try to parse the array objects under the main object? It's much easier to work with `jq`

Comment: @mkopriva the given snippet is just for decoding the json and that's the easy part. I want to know how can I control the output to implement some logic or parse the output so that I can work with nested objects.

Answer (score 4):

##### Use a steaming decoder

For starters, when you use `json.Unmarshal` you provide it all the bytes of the json input, so you need to read the entire source file *before* you can even start to allocate memory for your Go representation of the data.

I hardly ever use `json.Unmarshal`.  [Use `json.NewDecoder` like this](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-Decoder.Decode-Stream), which will stream the data into the unmarshaler bit by bit.

You'd still have to fit all of the data representation in memory (at least the parts you modeled), but depending on the data in the Json, that might be quite a bit less memory than the json representation.

For example, in JSON, numbers are represented as strings of digit characters, but can often fit into much smaller `int` or `float64` types.  booleans and nulls are also much bigger in Json than their Go representation.  The structure characters `[]{}:` probably won't require as much space in go in-memory types.  And of course any whitespace in the Json does nothing but make the file larger.   (I'd recommend minifying the json to remove unnecessary whitespace, but that's only relevant for storage and won't have much effect once you're streaming the json data).

##### Model your data with `struct`s and omit as much data from your model  as possible

If there's a lot of json data that isn't relevant to your operation, omit them from your models.

You can't do this if you're letting the decoder decode into generic types like `map[string]interface{}` .  But if you [use the struct based decoding mechanisms](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal), you can specify which fields you want to store, which might significantly decrease the size of your representation in memory.  Combined with the streaming decoder that might solve your memory constraint.

Clearly some of your data has unknown keys, so you can't store all of it in a structure.  If you can't sufficiently define the structures that match your data, this option's off the table.

##### Add memory or swap to your system

Memory is cheap these days, and disk space for swap is even cheaper.  If you can get away with adding either to alleviate your memory constraint, so you can fit all the data's representation in memory, that's by far the simplest solution to your problem.

##### Convert data to a format that can be more efficiently accessed in storage

Json is a great format and one of my favorites.  But it's not very good for storing large volumes of data because it's cumbersome to access subsets of that data at a time.

Formats like [parquet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Parquet) store data in a way that makes the underlying storage much more efficient to query and navigate.  This means that instead of reading all the data and then representing it all in memory, you can read the parts of the data you want directly from the on-disk storage.

The same would be true of a well indexed SQL or NoSQL database.

You could even break your data down into multiple json files that you could read and process sequentially.

##### Last resort, implement your own scanning functionality

If you really can't (or won't) add memory or swap space, change the format of the data, or break it into smaller parts, then you have to write a json scanner that can keep track of your location in the json file so that you know how to process the data.  You won't have a representation of all the data at once, but you might be able to pick out the pieces you need without having to store a representation of all the data at once.

It's complicated though, and would be specific to the task in question, there's no generic answer for how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. That's very kind of you.
I agree that memory is not a problem nowadays but I can't let a CLI tool consume 8+ GB memory in just a few seconds, this sounds like a serious issue to me (also this is just for 1 Gb file, I can't imagine how it would be for 10GB file). So none of the options I can use, unfortunately.
Breaking the file could be an option programmatically but would you be able to give an idea how to do that?

Comment: At least you should implement `json.NewDecoder` instead of `json.Unmarhsal`.  For breaking up, I'd suggest making it a memory intensive one time task to read whole file and write out many smaller files or into a database.